# haproxy: how to intercept links that point directly to the backend servers

Tags: haproxy

I have set up haproxy and it works fine, I can access web pages that sit on servers on the backend.

**The setup is as follow:**

There's a single frontend haproxy server that points to different backend depending on the port

- frontend:81 points to backend:8100
- frontend:82 points to backend:8200

On the frontend web page `http://frontend:82/` there are links like `http://frontend:82/foo` so whenever I click on one of these links haproxy makes sure to connect to the proper backend server. One of these link points to `http://backend:8200/bar` (backend server and different port).

If I click on that link I get redirected to the server on the backend rather than the frontend haproxy. Is there any way to intercept those calls to the backend servers?

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the link `http://backend:8200/bar`, unless the dns for 'backend' is pointing to your haproxy you're not going to catch the request.

Ports are probably not the best way to do this.

You would be better off having a frontend on 80, and using acls based on url

EG:

```
frontend http_frontend 
   bind *:80
   acl path_foo path_beg /foo
   acl path_barbar path_beg /bar 
   use_backend foo_backend if path_foo
   use_backend bar_backend if path_bar

backend foo_backend
   server backend:8200

backend bar_backend
   server backend:8100
```

That way you can strip all the port assignments out of the links.